# Group by hour in mysql but include the first value from the hour+1 also

Tags: mysql, group-by

Say you have data like this:

```
  time  value
  10:00   5
  10:15   12
  10:30   15
  10:45   27
  11:00   29
```

And a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(value) - MIN(value), HOUR(time) FROM mytable GROUP BY HOUR(time);
```

You will get:

```
  value  time
    22    10
```

But, I would need it to include the value at 11:00, thus the result being 24 (29-5), and not 22. Is there a way to do this in SQL or do I have no other choice than to do this manually in the code level (so, without the grouping, just fetching the data and manually subtracting).

Comment: You want to include both `10:00` and `11:00`?  Just remove the `group by` clause.

Comment: And do you still need values at 10:00 to be included?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I can't remove the group by because I want the results per hour. So, I'll have result of a max-min for all the hours of the current day.

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan: Yes, though am interested in how does this change the potential answer from you? Can you state the difference if 10:00 is included vs that it isn't?

Comment: Just to verify, you want the data point at 11:00 to both be part of the 10-11 interval, and the 11-12 interval?

Comment: @thebjorn: correct, exactly like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how consistent your data is, you might be able to do this with a self join, like so:

```
SELECT HOUR(a.`time`) AS grouper,
GREATEST(MAX(a.value),IFNULL(MIN(b.value),0)) - MIN(a.value) AS diff
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON IF(HOUR(a.time) <= 23, HOUR(a.time)+1, 0) = HOUR(b.time)
GROUP BY grouper
```

The `LEFT JOIN` on the same table allows you to get the next hour's value for comparison purposes.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe72a/16

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - but the value at 12 should be 1 (34-33) instead of -33. Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Yes add the GREATEST() method on diff so that it uses the next hour, if it exists, otherwise the largest value from the current hour. See updated SQL above, and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT hr, 
       max( value ) - min( value )
FROM mytable m
JOIN (
  SELECT  HOUR(`time`) hr, 
          cast(Date_Format(min(`time`),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as time) mt
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
) q
ON m.`time` >= q.mt 
AND m.`time` <= q.mt + interval 1 hour 
GROUP BY hr
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/012c7/9

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it seems your answer is perfect and I will accept it. However could you please give me a hint where am I going wrong when I incorporate this query to my bigger query which then looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ac9/8

Comment: I realized in the previous examples I had the wrong dataset (inversed) so the real one is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b0d4/1. And though, I'm still missing something to get the data, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the value of 11:00 to be part of both HOUR=10 and HOUR=11, I would use this UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT `time`, MAX(value) - MIN(value)
FROM (
  SELECT
    HOUR(`time`) AS `time`, value
  FROM
    mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CASE WHEN HOUR(`time`) > 0 THEN HOUR(`time`)-1 ELSE 23 END, value
  FROM
    mytable
  WHERE
    MINUTE(`time`)=0
) s
GROUP BY `time`
```

If you have a large amount of data, I would try to rethink your database structure since queries like this one can't be optimized much.